# Proof of income student visa extension Germany

Tags: germany, student-visa

I'm a international student (non-EEU) and a scholarship holder obtaining Master's Degree in Germany.

I initially planned to finish my studies in 4 semesters but due to certain circumstances I need one additional semester to finish my studies.

Now, my student visa and scholarship (non-extensible) expires in September 2018 but I would like to finish my studies.

The question is: **can part-time job contract be considered as a proof of income** for the application of student residence permit extension in Germany?

Comment: Normally you should probably save enough money in your bank account to prove that you have the money to last another year, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can try it. I'm not a lawyer, so cannot guarantee you anything, but at least I did from 2010 till 2013. If in doubt, you can always ask Ausländerbehörde in advance.

Besides this, one can combine multiple income sources. Let's say one needs to have 800 Euro netto per month, but a part-time job only gives 650 Euro. Then one can make an extra bank account and block there the missing 12 x 150 Euro in order to get a prolongation for one year. Again, it depends on Ausländerbehörde, but in my case such things were possible.

Answer (score -1):

**No.**

A work contract is not considered as proof of financial resources. The rational behind this is: you lose your job - you have no income.